# Dinamic table with PdfMake

Tags: pdfmake

It dont display in format. I'm using Angular 8.

This part is for getting the info.

```
var med = MyData....;//[name,price,description]
var col = [];

med.forEach(element => {
  var row=[];
  row.push([element.name]);
  row.push([element.price])
  row.push([element.description]);
  console.log(row);

  col.push(row);
});
```

then this part is for displaying in pdfMake

```
let dd= {
  content: [
        {
            table: {
                `body`: [
                    col
                ]
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

Sometimes it displays vertically.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you phrase your actual question? Please describe what your actual output is and what you wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In pdfmake.org/playground.html when you put this code:

```
var ex = [['example 1', '10','d1'],['example 2', '12','d2'], ['example 3', '18','d3']];
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                widths:['auto','auto','*'],
                body: [
                    ['name', 'price ','description'],
                    ex
                ]
            }
        },
    ]

}
```

[this is te result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CADe.png)

and I need something like this, **no matter how much values I get in my array**:

```
    var ex = [['example 1', '10','d1'],['example 2', '12','d2'], ['example 3', '18','d3']];
var dd = {
    content: [
        {
            style: 'tableExample',
            table: {
                widths:['auto','auto','*'],
                body: [
                    ['name', 'price ','description'],
                    ex[0],
                    ex[1],
                    ex[2]
                ]
            }
        },
    ]

}
```

[I need this result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpTKF.png)